# Задать цвет для ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть ImageView, который нужно изменять по цвету в зависимости от входных данных. Сделать это нужно внутри метода OnBindViewHolder (class RecycleView.Adapter). Сам метод:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    el = elems.get(position);
    
    name.setText(el.name); //это работает, проблем с объявлением быть не должно
    date.setText(el.date);
    poroda.setText(el.poroda);

    switch (el.color){ //переменная color объявлена выше, как  ImageView
        case("Белый"): color.setBackground(null); break; //тут нужно задавать цвета
        case("Синий"): color.setColorFilter(500043); break;
        case("Красный"): color.setColorFilter(500056); break;
        case("Желтый"): color.setColorFilter(500020); break;
        case("Зеленый"): color.setColorFilter(500096); break;
        default: break;
    }
```

Верстка ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im_color"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:backgroundTint="#03A9F4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

@drawable/border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thickness="0dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#0D151C"/>
<corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Надо что-то типа:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Context.getColor(R.color.white));
```

При этом в ресурсах надо завести `color.xml`, навроде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: 23+? счастливые люди )

Comment: Эмм... доля 23+ около 87%, да и к тому же `setColorFilter(int )` доступен с 8+ - или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: `Context.getColor` - 23+. А так `ContextCompat.getColor` повсеместно...